# Adding and removing class to a div when checkbox changed in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am displaying some data using `ng-repeat` in my HTML page.

```
<div class="list-expense-menu-item" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
  <md-checkbox aria-label="Checkbox" ng-model="ch" ng-change="changeClass(ch)" >   </md-checkbox>
  <div class="col-80">
    <p class="header">{{todo.note}}</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I want to add a `class` to the second `div` (i.e. div with class `col-80`) when check box is checked, and remove the `class` when unchecked

**Controller.js**

```
$scope.ch=false;
    $scope.changeClass=function(val){
       alert(val);
       if(val){
         //add class text-strick
        }else{
          //remove class text-strick
        }
      }
```

I will get true and false values in `alert` ,but i don't know how add and remove the class when checkbox changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to link the checkbox with the todos object that is repeating in ng-repeat. From your question I am understanding that you want to highlight the div next to the checkbox, so since there will be multiple pairs of checkbox and div, something like this will work:

```
<div class="list-expense-menu-item" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    <md-checkbox aria-label="Checkbox" ng-model="todo.ch"></md-checkbox>
   <div class="col-80" ng-class="{'className':todo.ch}">
     <p class="header">{{todo.note}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need for `todo.ch == true`., `todo.ch` itself will be a boolean.

Comment: Agreed, but the main point of my answer was to make the syntax clear for the expression of ng-class, your point is definately correct though